# How to evaluate variable content as php code?

Tags: php

i want to be able to write some code that would contain html and php and then save it in a variable and print it  where i need it but i dont know to make the php code inside the variable go through the php compiler before beeing send to the browser.

example:

```
$var='echo "Hello World"';

echo $var;
```

output is **echo "Hello World"**.

but i want the output to be **Hello World**.

Can someone explain me how to do this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`eval`](http://www.php.net/eval). You should not do this and/or use this unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Your "problem" is created by you. Don't create a problem. Use included files.

Answer (score 2):

its very simple,
you can use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function

```
<?php
         $var='echo "Hello World"';
        echo substr($var,5);  //output "Hello World"
 ?>
```

===========================================================

```
<?php
         $var='echo "Hello World"';
         echo substr(substr($var,6),0,-1); //out put Hello World
 ?>
```